# selenium testing page that requires a login

Tags: java, selenium

I have this gherkin file

```
    Scenario: Person Creation
       Given user logged in on the creation interface 
       When user populates the form and clicks create and the person is created
```

and I can't do the second step without login so I merge it in one step like

```
Scenario: Persons Creation
Given user logged in and populates the form and click create and logout
```

and here is the implementation in selenium the data used in the loop are imported from excel files

```
 @Given("user logged in and populates the form and click create and logout")
public void user_logged_in_and_populates_the_form_and_click_create_and_logout() throws InterruptedException {
    userLoginCreationPage.init();
    logger.info("**************************************** init the driver && go to creation page http://localhost:4200/login");

    for (UserLoginPageData userLoginPageData : userLoginPageDataList) {
        logger.info("Line  " + userLoginPageData.getRowIndex() + "from Excel file");
        userLoginCreationPage.enterUsername(userLoginPageData.getUsername());
        userLoginCreationPage.enterPassword(userLoginPageData.getPassword());
        userLoginCreationPage.clickOnLogin();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        logger.info(userLoginPageData.toString() + "is login");
        personCreationPage.init();
        logger.info("**************************************** init the driver && go to creation page http://localhost:4200/dossier-person/new");
        for (PersonPageData personPageData : personPageDataList) {
            if (userLoginPageData.getIdUser().equals(personPageData.getIdUser())) {
                personCreationPage.refresh();
                personCreationPage.enterUsername(personPageData.getUsername());
                personCreationPage.enterEmail(personPageData.getEmail());
                personCreationPage.enterPassword(personPageData.getPassword());
                personCreationPage.clickTab();
                personCreationPage.clickOnCreate();
                Thread.sleep(500);
                logger.info(personPageData.toString() + " ****************************************  is created by " + userLoginPageData.getUsername());
            }
        }
        userLoginCreationPage.clickOnLogout();
    }

}
```

what I need I to use two method like this

```
void userLoggedInOnTheCreationInterface(){}
void userPopulatesTheForm(){}
```